# angularjs using in typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am beginner for angular, I want  to use angular js in typescript,

I refer this link 'https://gist.github.com/esfand/9569523' I get error is displayed below image, please help to solve this problem

[image]

Comment: could you add your source code please?

Comment: Angular js 1 is completely code will be on JS. Angular js 2 uses typescript

Comment: If you will to use AngularJS with typescript you need to add type for AngularJS. Install with this: npm install --save @types/angular

Answer (score 0):

You have errors `Unexpected token`. You cannot run TypeScript directly. *You need to compile TypeScript before running it*.

## More

A browser quickstart for TypeScript using webpack https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html